# Spring bean where class is filtered...or how to choose between two beans?

Tags: java, spring, maven, javabeans, maven-3

I have several XA datasources I need to configure within a Spring application context that I use for integration testing inside of Maven.  They look like this:

```
<bean id="sbeH2XADataSource" class="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="$DS{hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="$DS{hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="$DS{hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sbeMySQLXADataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="$DS{hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="$DS{hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="$DS{hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>
```

Ideally, I'd use Maven filtering to set the bean class, but Spring doesn't like that (at least not Spring tooling in Eclipse).  I really would like to avoid making both beans and rather just make the one.  In the event I have to make both and use only one, how does one create a bean "ref" that is dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a property place holder for the ref value and configure which bean to use from your properties file.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, but something else must have been wrong.  I created another question related to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801802/create-spring-bean-where-class-is-a-string) and tried it again and it worked with Maven filtering...go figure!

Comment: Ya, sometimes eclipse behaves a little weird. You can use the eclipse problem tab to see what errors your project has beyond compilation. Every now and then that saves me.

Answer (score 1):

Check spring [bean definition profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/). They allow you to have beans registered depending on the environment.