# Create Spring Bean where class is a string?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, javabeans, factory

Is there some kind of bean factory or static class that I can use within a Spring configuration file to create an instance of a Java class and set its properties?  Something like this:

```
<bean id="myThingy" class="org.whatever.specialBeanMaker">
     <property class="${maven.filtered.property.value}" />
     <properties>
        <property name="a" value="...." />
        <property name="b" value="...." />
        <property name="c" value="...." />
     </properties>
</bean>
```

In other words, I need to make a bean from a class I won't know until runtime (because of filtering, JNDI, propertyPlaceholderConfigurer, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for anything special. Just do it like you'd expect:

```
<bean class="${whateverClass}"/>
```

Comment: I tried that earlier expecting it to work and Eclipse/Spring-Tools was throwing a build error.  Then I tried it just now and it worked!  The error must have been from something else.  In any event...thanks.